# How to show dialog box if the value is only equal to 1?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

Right now my dialog box open when ever I open the site but I'm just wondering how I to make the dialog to open only if the notificationType is equal to 1.

There are multiple type of notification and I only want the dialog open if the notificationType is equal to 1 so how do I check inside my getNotification call?. any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

I can have multiple type of notification in my get call and I want to find all the index and check if there is any notificationType 1 and if there is then show the dialog box. If there is no notificationType 1 in all the index then don't show the dialog box.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.notificationService.getNotification().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.broadcastText.next(response);
      if(response && response.length){
        this.dialog.open(ReleaseDialogComponent, {
          data : {notifications: response}
        });
      }

    })
```

[image]

Comment: ...check the response and see if `notificationType === 1` and if so, call `this.dialog.open`?

Comment: Hi.. I've update my question and hope it's more clear now. thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(response && response.length && response[0].notificationType === 1)` should do the trick.

EDIT:
Based on response, if you want to avoid doing response[0], and assuming you have to open the dialog if notificacionType === 1 is present ANY item os the response, you can do something like this:

```
if(response && response.length) {
  // This will return true if notificationType === 1 is any response item
  const shouldShowNotification = response.some(el => el.notificationType === 1);

  if (shouldShowNotification) {
    this.dialog.open(ReleaseDialogComponent, {
          data : {notifications: response}
    });
  }
}
```

If dialog opens anyways despite notificationType, I'm afraid you have another problem.

Comment: Sadly this is not working. it's still showing the dialog box for some reason. ;(. also how to not do response[0] because sometime I get multiple notification types in one call and the 0 index can be notificationType 2 and index 3 can be notifactionType 1.

Comment: @AaseZi That's the kind of important details that should be in the question...

Comment: @AaseZi I updated the response to handle multiple notifications in response. Unfortunately, if the dialog is still showing, maybe you have a problem in the way you are calling it

Comment: @RamiroP It work...Thank you so much. really appreciated it for your help. :)